# What exactly is /lib/modules/4.4.0-XX-generic/vdso/.build-id

Tags: kernel, cleanup, chkrootkit

I did a rootkit search with chkrootkit and it came up with this strange set of files:

```
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/vdso/.build-id
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/vdso/.build-id
```

What exactly are these? I'm fairly certain they're all false positives, but I still don't know what they are and why they're there. I did a bit of search and it looks like these are kernel images left behind from previous updates.

So why are they setting off a false positive and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

`/lib/modules/` is the directory to store modules. The next bit (with the digits) is the kernel number these modules belong to.

`vdso` in the name of the module (it stands for `virtual dynamic shared object`). Your system does a lot of "system calls"  (like reading and writing to disk, grant permissions, etc) and it takes up a lot of resources to perform each of these. But those calls are also done a lot. The `vdso` module was created to help improving the time needed by allocating memory for them.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO):

> vDSO (virtual dynamically linked shared object) is a Linux kernel mechanism for exporting a carefully selected set of kernel space routines to user space applications so that applications can call these kernel space routines in-process, without incurring the performance penalty of a context switch that is inherent when calling these same kernel space routines by means of the system call interface.

Some more information on this:

- gitbooks: [part 1](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-1.html), [part 2](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-2.html), [part 3](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-3.html) all about system calls. Part 2 is about "vdso" and "vsyscall".

> I'm fairly certain they're all false positives

Probably (as with 99.999999% of all those rootkits notices ;) ) but you probably need to compare these files with a clean system and check things like file size, last modification times to visually check if this is a false positive.

---

By the way: the `/lib/modules/` directory can get large quickly. It is safe to remove old kernels (save the current and the next least oldest just to make sure you got a backup). See: [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Removing the older version also lowers the amount of notices from your rootkit ;)

Comment: Yeah, these were all last modified months ago when I updated, so they're false positives. Now, is it possible to just delete them directly from the folder, or should I use the program in the link you posted (synaptic)?

Comment: You need to follow a "how to delete old kernels" method (synaptic is not really needed for this; there are other methods) Otherwise you remove parts of the kernel and have leftovers elsewhere :)

Comment: Do you have any idea why this might set off chkrootkit? I'm not really sure *how* it works, but maybe that's another post.

Answer (score 0):

I saw these on a rootkit scan of a test VM (ubuntu 18.04 LTS), and deleted them. No noticeable side effects on the system, although they appear to be in use by the OS as it is repopulated on a reboot.